# In mesh analysis how are currents negative and positive?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I'm trying to do mesh analysis for the following circuit. I take the clockwise direction for the current as it's general convention.

[image]

The reference shows that this results in

[image]

I don't understand how the +,- terminals are marked for resistance and how VS1 becomes negative. Can someone help?

Comment: What happened to R3?

Comment: @Andyaka lol .. the reference itself seems to be wrong.Its from here http://www.daenotes.com/electronics/basic-electronics/mesh-current-method

Comment: Vs2= R2(I2-I1)+R3I2 and direction is opposite because current direction is opposite for Vs2 comparing with Vs1. Have a look.

Comment: @Electroholic okay...thanks ..nut what about R3I2.. doesnt the sign conventions appy to the resistor and how to mark the resistor ends as +ve or -ve?

Comment: Do not follow polarity shown on resistor, it can be misleading ( or just to mislead or to confuse ). Just follow direction of current.

Comment: @Electroholic But how do you even mark the polarity ..its not given already

Comment: Simple thing to remember, To get voltage drop across resistor, mark it with positive sign { R X its ( corresponding loop current + Loop current having same direction to the corresponding  loop, if any - Loop current having opposite direction to the corresponding loop, if any )}.

Comment: @Electroholic did not get what you have meant..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@elecman, let's work this out together and see how they got what they got.

The +ve and -ve terminals for Vs1 and Vs2 are noted by their longer and shorter lines. Longer line is for **+ve terminal**, shorter line is for **-ve terminal**.

Now when doing a Mesh Analysis, **(IF NOT PREVIOUSLY STATED)** the polarity of the resistor depends on the direction of the current going through that resistor.

Basically there is a voltage drop from the point when the current **enters** the resistor and the point when it **leaves** the resistor. Resistors "**resist (more like reduce)**" current flow, and thus **lower** the voltage levels within a circuit.

So for Loop 1, we have the current I1. Since I1 enters the Resistor R1 on the left side of the *zigzag* first, the left side is considered **+ve** and since it leaves the right side of the *zigzag* last, the right side of Resistor R1 is considered **-ve**. So If I1 was going in the opposite direction, thus entering the resistor R1 on the right side of the *zigzag* and leaving at the left side of the *zigzag*, the polarities of R1 will be opposite.

As for Resistor R2 we have a current I3. I3 however depends on the final battle/result between currents I1 and I2. Now I3 can go either way, it can enter R2 from the top and leave at the bottom or it can enter from the bottom and leave at the top. Since we are still in Loop 1, we want I3 to go in the same direction of I1 to keep everything simple, thus we want it to enter the top of Resistor R2 (making the top of the *zigzag* the **+ve**) and leave at the bottom of R2 (making the bottom of the *zigzag* the **-ve**). However in order for I3 to do that, I1 must be stronger than the opposite current going through that same resistor which is I2. Thus as for now in Loop 1, **I3 = (I1 - I2)**.

Now we want to come up with the mesh equation for Loop 1: Following in the direction of current I1,

-Vs1 + I1 * R1 + (I1 - I2) * R2 = 0

**Vs1 = I1 * R1 + (I1 - I2) * R2** **--------- EQUATION 1**

As for Loop 2, we have the current I2. Since we want the current entering R2 to be in the direction of I2 (from bottom to top making the bottom terminal of the *zigzag* of Resistor R2 **+ve** and the top terminal of the *zigzag* **+ve**), current I2 must be stronger than the opposite current I1. Thus in this case **I3 = (I2 - I1).**

As for Resistor R3, the current I2 is entering the left side of the *zigzag*, thus making that side the **+ve** terminal and leaving the right side of the *zigzag*, thus making that side the **-ve** terminal.

Now we want to come up with the mesh equation for Loop 2: Following in the direction of current I2,

(I2 - I1) * R2 + I2 * R3 + Vs2 = 0

**-Vs2 = I2 * R3 + (I2 - I1) * R2** **--------- EQUATION 2**

**I GUESS THAT R1 IN THE SECOND EQUATION FROM THEIR RESULTS SHOULD BE R3.**

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i will solve this on my own before seeing your answer :).. so that i can compare

Comment: @elecman, thats good.

Comment: Same equation,we got:) and thanks a lot for explaining the basics in detail.Much appreciated :) .Again i cant upvote since my rep is below 15.

Comment: @elecman, no problem. As long as you've understood it, Im okay with it.

Comment: can you please help me with this too http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/226337/mesh-analysis-for-circuit-having-current-source

Answer (score 1):

I think the equation is wrong or they are using a different assumption. Basically, The direction of flow of current is clockwise as seen in mesh. While speaking of resistor, the entry is taken positive and exit is taken negative but always take the exit as the polarity. Now since the direction of current is clockwise(from left to right) it aligns with direction of resistance meaning current having the same direction as resistor to you will take negative sign(-ve). So the equation becomes -(I1R1), again the direction of current is downward and the exit sign is again negative so the other part becomes -I2R2. Now when going towards the voltage source. The longer line is positive end and the shorter one is negative end. Now in that branch current direction in from bottom to top and the exit sign of voltage source is postive to it'll become +VS1. The final equation is:-I1R1-I2R2+VS1=0. Note: here sign means polarity(-,+)